# codeigniter - how to create more than one set of pagination links on one view

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

**Problem Description**

I have a situation where I have parent / child tables that I have to display on the same view - in two different
sections. Each section needs its own set of pagination links. The contents (and therefore, pagination links) in section 2 must change depending on what is selected in the parent section / section 1.
So specifically, I have a categories table, and for each category, i have products within.  I'd like to show a list of categories on the top of the page, and the bottom will display the products, if any, in the selected category.

**First Attempt:**

I've tried to solve this problem 2 different ways.  The first time I wrote the code, I had one method in the controller which would look up all subcategories based on an id that the user selected.  It looked something like this:

```
    public function browsecategory($category_id)
    {               
        //find all products in category.            
        $this->load->model('category/product_category_model');  

                    //pagination for products
        $this->load->library('pagination');

        $config['base_url'] = site_url('/product/browsecategory/'.$category_id);
        $config['uri_segment'] = 4;
        $config['total_rows'] = count($productrecords);
        $config['per_page'] = 10;
        $config['num_links'] = 10;

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $offset = ($this->uri->segment($config['uri_segment'])) ? $this->uri->segment($config['uri_segment']) : 0;

        $productrecords = $this->product_model->limit($config['per_page'], $offset)->find_all();

                    //find any subcategories for this category
        $this->load->model('category/category_model');

                  //pagination for subcategories
        $this->load->library('pagination');

        $config['base_url'] = site_url('/product/browsecategory/'.$category_id);
        $config['uri_segment'] = 5;
        $config['total_rows'] = count($this->category_model->find_all_by('parent_id', $category_id););
        $config['per_page'] = 10;
        $config['num_links'] = 10;

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $offset = ($this->uri->segment($config['uri_segment'])) ? 

                    $this->uri->segment($config['uri_segment']) : 0;    
                    $subcategoriesrecords = $this->category_model->limit($config['per_page'], $offset)->find_all_by('parent_id', $category_id);

        Template::set('categorydetails', $categorydetails);
        Template::set('productrecords', $productrecords);
        Template::set('subcategoriesrecords', $subcategoriesrecords);
        Template::render();
    }//end browsecategory
```

The view looked something like this:

```
    <?php if (isset($subcategoriesrecords) && is_array($subcategoriesrecords) && count($subcategoriesrecords)) : ?>
   <?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?> 
    <div>
        <h1 class="page-header">Sub-categories in <i> <?php echo $categorydetails->title; ?></i>:</h1>
    </div>
    <br />  
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">

        </table>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if (isset($productrecords) && is_array($productrecords) && count($productrecords)) : ?>
    <?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?> 
    <div>
        <h1 class="page-header">Products in category <i> <?php echo $categorydetails->title; ?></i>:</h1>
    </div>
    <br />  

    <?php endif; ?>
```

This didn't work because i realize that i was really only creating one pagination object.  Although I had two sets of code, one for each dataset, I was overwritting ( i think) the first pagination object with the second one I declared. 
In any case, when the system would dislpay the two sets of data on the view, clicking on the pagination links for products would trigger paging for the categories.  No matter what I did, I couldn't page through the products.

**Second Attempt**

I decided to try to use ajax.  So in my controller, i split up the functionality to look up the categories and products into two methods, like so:

```
    public function browsecategory($category_id)
    {               
        //find any subcategories for this category
        $this->load->model('category/category_model');
        $this->load->model('category/product_category_model');  
        $subcategoriesrecords = $this->category_model->find_all_by('parent_id', $category_id);

        //look up category information ... used for display purposes. 
        $categorydetails = $this->category_model->find_by('category_id', $category_id);

        //pagination for subcategories  
        $this->load->library('pagination');

        $config['base_url'] = site_url('/product/browsecategory/'.$category_id);
        $config['uri_segment'] = 4;
        $config['total_rows'] = count($subcategoriesrecords);
        $config['per_page'] = 5;
        $config['num_links'] = 10;

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $offset = ($this->uri->segment($config['uri_segment'])) ? $this->uri->segment($config['uri_segment']) : 0;
        $subcategoriesrecords = $this->category_model->limit($config['per_page'], $offset)->find_all_by('parent_id',$category_id);

        //check for any products within this current category.. if exists, include ajax to display

        if ( count ($this->product_category_model->find_all_by('category_id', $category_id)) > 0 ) {
            //add jquery logic to call getproductsincategory on document load

            $inline = "$.ajax({
              url:'http://myserver/myapp/product/getproductsincategory/".$category_id."',
              type:'POST',
              dataType:'html',
              contentType : 'text/html',
              success: function(returnDataFromController) {

        $('#products').html(returnDataFromController);
                },
                error:  function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                {
                          alert(errorThrown);
                }
            }); 
                ";
            Assets::add_js( $inline, 'inline' );
        }
        Template::set('categorydetails', $categorydetails);
        Template::set('subcategoriesrecords', $subcategoriesrecords);
        Template::render();
    }//end browsecategory


    public function getproductsincategory($category_id)
    {
        //find all products in category.            
        $this->load->model('category/product_category_model');  
        $this->load->model('category/category_model');

        //pagination for prodcuts
        $this->load->library('pagination');

        $config['base_url'] = site_url('/product/browsecategory/'.$category_id);
        $config['uri_segment'] = 5;
        $config['total_rows'] = count($productrecords);
        $config['per_page'] = 10;
        $config['num_links'] = 10;

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $offset = ($this->uri->segment($config['uri_segment'])) ?                 $this->uri->segment($config['uri_segment']) : 0;
        $productrecords = $this->product_model->limit($config['per_page'], $offset)->find_all_by('category_id',$category_id);

                    //build html string for displaying products

        print $htmlstring;      
    }
```

Sadly, i still have the same results.  The system displays two sets of links, but they only seem to be tied to the categories.  I cannot page through products using the product pagination links.

Can someone tell me if this can be done... and if so, where I'm going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: try passing the create_links from controller $data['FirstLinks'] = $this->pagination->create_links(); etc . (not tested) but I guess it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/AJAX-Pagination-with-CI-Pagination-Library There are also a bunch of tutorials out here on how to use it https://www.google.com/search?q=codeigniter+pagination+ajax

I think the main issue is that the generated pagination links are simply an href to the next/previous/first/last results. You will want to override the second set of pagination links so that they request and re-populate the second pane with the new data.